# how to add this to my .aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I recently downloaded an event calendar from this link:

http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/club/EventCalendar.zip

I want to use this in my website, however what's inside is just a bunch of .cs file. How can I integrate this with my .aspx page? Sorry if this seems like a pretty noob question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the EventCalendar CS project and compile the application.  This will build a DLL.  Now, in your application, click Add Reference and locate the Event Calendar DLL that has just compiled.  Once you have added the reference, you'll need to add the namespace to the top of your code where you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the .cs files into a DLL and add the DLL to your web site.  If your web site is already a .NET ASPX project you should just need to add the .cs files to your project (assuming they don't have any dependencies to other DLLs).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, just add all of these files to your ASP.NET project. Then you should be able to add an instance of EventCalendar to your application.

Once you get that working, it would probably be cleaner to create a new "library" project that contains all of these files, so they are compiled into their own DLL. Then just add a reference to that project from your main one, and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate project, just open it up on its own in VS and compile (build) it. Then, plop the generated release DLL in the bin folder of your project and add a reference to it :-)